# I need to maintain both sdk (3.0 and 4.0). But in 3.0 sdk I am getting error

Tags: iphone, uiview

I need to maintain both sdk (3.0 and 4.0). But in 3.0 sdk I am getting error.

```
CGFloat maxScale;

if ( [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector (scale)] == YES )
{
    maxScale = 1.0 / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
}
else 
{
    maxScale = 1.0;
}


warning: 'UIScreen' may not respond to '-scale'
error: invalid operands to binary / (have 'double' and 'id')
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like apple had built in scale as an id type in 3.0 but not made it useful/usable. perhaps trying to test the version (even though that is widely regarded as not best practices) might be the only option here.

Comment: Do you really need to **build** your project with sdk 3.0?

Comment: I set latest SDK =4.1 and set  iOS Deployment Target = 3.0 . It works well on simulator. But when I am installing on real 3g iphone i get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your code to be different when you build with different SDK versions then you need to use preprocessor:

```
#if __IPHONE_4_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED

     maxScale = 1.0 / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

#else

     maxScale = 1.0;
#endif
```

But normally you do not need that, build your project with the latest SDK you have and set appropriate value to the "iOS Deployment Target" property of your target. Then your application will run on sdk versions you specified and code you have will make **run-time** check if `-scale` method is present.